# Google Sheets - Copy row to bottom of data in the sheet each day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a script to copy a row of data in google sheets to the bottom of a list
i.e. A2:L2 data gets copied and pasted to a new row at the bottom of the sheet. If there's no row available then it creates a new row and copies the data in there.
I'd then have this run on a time trigger at the end of each day

Any idea why this is not working?

```
    function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PERFORMANCE");
  var source = sheet.getRange("A2:L2");
  var values = source.getValues();
  values[0][0] = new Date();
  sheet.appendRow(values[0]);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with is not working? What do you see instead?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
function appendMyNewRow() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName("PERFORMANCE");
  //const sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const shsr=2;
  const vs=sh.getRange(shsr,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs[0][0]=new Date();
  sh.appendRow(vs[0]);
}
```